# Why does the Shell script not running in Super User mode?

Tags: linux, sh

Folks, I'm trying to run a shell script which will execute two commands,

The Coding for my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo sudo su
echo "working"
```

When I run this script the first line works good, It asks for the password and I entered the password after entering the password it changed as the Super user. Now the problem is the second line is not working since the user is changed.

Once I type `exit` it runs the second line of code

But I want both the lines to be executed.

How can I achieve this? I need to run the second line in the super user mode but it runs only after the exit of super user mode.

Comment: `echo sudo su` - O'Really?

Comment: I forget to mention `` but in code its correct (I couldn't do ` ` in stackoverflow )

Comment: I just don't know how to do it can you please guide me...

Comment: I fixed your editing (indent blocks of code, don't use backquotes for each line), so you can add the backquotes where they occur in your actual code. They aren't necessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su -c "echo working; id"
```

Note: The `id` command will prove that the `echo` command indeed ran in super user mode.

Comment: or use `echo $USER`